# C# any Lambda Statement as Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have the following problem: I need to create function which takes any Lambda (with any parameters/return type) as a parameter. For lambda expressions it works fine with this type: LambdaExpression

But if i have a lambda statement (eg containing a assignment) i couldn't find a corresponding type. Any ideas how i could do that?

Corresponding Error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0834?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0834)

Example for my code would be (i will call the lambda dynamically and take care of any amount/type of paramteres required; i will create special provides which provide data dependent on the types):

```
 MyClass.Call((Person person) => {
        ...
 });
```

Or

```
 MyClass.Call((string id, int otherId) => {
        ...
 });
```

Comment: Sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this? How is a lambda expression that could literally be anything, useful?

Comment: I want to implement a simple framework, where i get any lambda expression as parameter and dynamically call it with corresponding paramters provided by the framework

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very safe design. What if I pass in a lambda that takes too many parameters? What's stopping you from using the built-in delegates, like `Action<T>`? Please show a [mcve] demonstrating why.

Comment: Because i want to dynamically bind the parameters, if you require more params i will pass more params - i will add an example to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#natural-function-type), the compiler can now infer a natural type for lambda expressions.

So you can take in a `Delegate`, and the caller can put in any lambda expression.

```
public static void Call(Delegate d) { ... }
```

Caller:

```
// These all compile:
Call(() => { ... });
Call((Person p) => { ... });
Call((string s, int n) => { .... });
```

In the method, I suppose you need to inspect what parameters the lambda takes. You can do this by reflection.

```
ParameterInfo[] parameters = d.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters();
// ... some logic that provides parameters according to the parameters array

// call the lambda with DynamicInvoke
d.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { ... });
// or by invoking "Invoke" using reflection.
```

That said, I doubt whatever framework you are writing can handle all types of lambda expressions. A lambda expression can have `ref`/`out`/`in` parameters of any type. The caller can pass in all kinds of weird things. This design itself is rather fragile.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks! It's fragile, but it works  fine
I couldn't think of a better solution to keep it that dynamic