# How to use a delegate that takes any number of parameters of any type?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a function that can take a function as parameter. I want that function to be any function I want.

```
    internal delegate void Callback(params object[] parameters);

    internal static void DamageTarget(Collider[] targets) {
      foreach (Collider target in targets) {
        EnemyHurtTest enemyScript = GetScript<EnemyHurtTest>(target);
        enemyScript.Damage();
      }
    }

    internal static void ApplySphereZoneDamage(Vector3 origin, float radius, LayerMask mask, string[] tags, Callback action) {
      List<Collider> targets = Physics.OverlapSphere(origin, radius, mask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide).ToList().FindAll(col => !HasTags(col, tags));

      if (targets.Count == 0) return;

      action(targets);
    }

      if (targets.Count == 0) return;

      action(targets);
    }

// When I call it :

    ApplySphereZoneDamage(origin, radius: 2f, am.hammerMask, tags, DamageTarget);
```

I have an error on "DamageTarget" saying "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Helpers.General.Callback'

What can I do to have a generic "Callback" delegate that I can use to pass any function as argument to other functions ?

Comment: C#/.NET doesn't support variadic generics - the `params T[]` syntactial sugar is the best you can get.

Comment: _"What can I do to have a generic "Callback" delegate that I can use to pass any function as argument to other functions ?"_ - You can't and you shouldn't. If your domain-model calls for parameterization of method arguments then you'll have to use [a parameter-object](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object). (The parameter-object can always be a `struct` so you can avoid the typical alloc/GC overhead of new-ing up objects)

Comment: You should ask yourself: how would you ever *call* that delegate, when you don't know its parameters? You should definitly rethink your solution.

Comment: ^^ _Wanting_ to do that should ring an Alarmbell, already.

Comment: In your example, why not just make your callback `void ColliderCallback(IEnumerable<Collider> targets)` ?   Or just use the generic delegate: `Action<IEnumerable<Collider>>` ? Why do you want to convert the parameters to object at all? If you want to use callbacks in different circumstances, just declare a new delegate, or use one of the generic ones.

Comment: [This answer of mine is related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75785863/5133585), but your possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) could probably be solved in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys ! Yeah I ended up making it a "Collider[] targets only" delegate.

Why the IEnumerable though ?

Comment: @BenjaminA A parameter typed as `IEnumerable<T>` can accept any collection type over `T` as an argument, including `List<T>`, `ImmutableList<T>` and `T[]`, whereas using `T[]` as a parameter-type means being able to accept _only_ (mutable) arrays. Additionally `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant over `T` which has other benefits. Generally speaking, when a method accepts any kind of collection it should use a covariant read-only collection interface, as it _signifies intent_ that the method will only read from the argument and not mutate it (because C# doesn't support `const` params)